# Nginx cross domain redirect without changing url in browser

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running nginx on an aws ec2 with ssl and a cert serving website content over https.

I am trying to use nginx to redirect requests from my ec2 server to an aws s3 bucket url like this https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_url

So if the ec2 url is example.com and someone visits it, they are redirected to the s3 url

**I do not want the example.com url to change to the s3 url - this is my problem**

so far i have used proxy pass and 301 but that just forwards the request to the s3 url

This is the most relevant question I have found however it does not work.

https://serverfault.com/questions/396595/nginx-proxy-domain-to-another-domain-with-no-change-url

I would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction

Comment: Proxy is the correct choose, or you'll need to implement this in application layer instead of web server. And be aware that AWS is deprecating the S3 URL you're using, please see: https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/

Comment: Do you really need the ec2 instance? You could just go Route53 -> Cloudfront -> S3.

Comment: `CloudFront` is the best option to achieve this.